# Visual Studio 2015 C# console application with ConfigurationManager does not generate correct config file

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a very simple C# console (.NET 4.5) application in Visual Studio 2015 Community edition. If I go in project properties, and go to settings a can "add settings" to my application. It adds the designer to my project and I can insert some new application settings which are then in my app.config, that was also added to my project.

In my code I use the ConfigurationManager object (as the ConfigurationSettings class is no longer to be used). I added the correct assembly (which seems to be an often missed thing, but I got that covered) and the program builds.

However, ConfigurationManager always returns null for any configuration parameter. I found some articles explaining the applicationSettings section in the config file is not correct, and this should be replaced with the much simpler appSettings section.

Even though I could change the app.config manually, how/why is Visual Studio not doing this correct so that I can work on my application and do not have to worry about the layout of automatically generated settings file? Is there some setting I have to use in Visual Studio such that these config files are correct in format and function, I can use the project properties and just hit the run/debug button? Is this a known issue in Visual Studio?

Comment: Perhaps you could post an example of your configuration and the code that is accessing it?

Comment: Can't you access them using `Properties.Settings.Default.propName`?

Comment: @codroipo Yes I can access the properties using your proposed code. Which is a good thing as I can now continue developing with one worry less... however, still don't understand why the advise is to use ConfigurationManager while by default this does not function correct. Thx for the help and the fast reply